# asp.net sql datasource bounded devexpress combobox add item

Tags: asp.net, combobox, devexpress

Hello i have devexpress combobox bounded with a sql datasource.I'am autocompleting items from datasource by using

`OnItemsRequestedByFilterCondition` function

i am filtering the items and binding filtered datasource to combobox

i want to add a "select All" item to top of the filtered results.

İ have already tried

```
combobox.Items.Add(0,new ListEditItem(-1,"Select All"));
```

but that does not work. I found soluiton for other datasources such list etc but not for sql datasource.Any clue would be helpful thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`combobox.Items.Add(0,new ListEditItem(-1,"Select All"));`  might be getting called before when you bind the combobox to the datasource.

The best way would be add this same field on the data source or add the item after you have binded the combobox with the data.

Comment: thank you for your answer i have tried both before binding and after binding datasource since i am using a sql datasource i am getting all data from database and do not want to add a meaningless record also if i insert to database a tupple that tupple will be filtered too it should be always there.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the different method signatures for Add(), when Add accepts 2 parameters it takes (string text, object value).  Insert() on the other hand is accepts (int index, ListEditItem item).  Try to use the Insert method as follows:

```
combobox.Items.Insert(0, new ListEditItem("Select All", -1);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but insert add does the same funciton except that insert takes an index parameter.Whatever i tried both and still cant add the item to top.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to add the -1 item before the data is bound

Problem I see you have is your binding to SQL data directly where I bind to objects that are derived from SQL calls.  For example:

```
var contractors = ContractorCollection.GetAll().Active();
contractors.Sort(new Contractor.NameAscending());

contractors.Insert(0, new Contractor() { ID = -1, Name = "Not Applicable or Required" });
this.cboContractors.TextField = "Name";
this.cboContractors.ValueField = "ID";
this.cboContractors.DataSource = contractors;
this.cboContractors.DataBind();
```

As you can see I am using a Collection which is built from a SPROC call internally. This populates the collection which is then bound in code.

I suspect your binding to a SQLDataSource control?